# How can I load an NSImage representation of the icon for my application?

Tags: cocoa, icons, nsimage

I have a custom icon file (MyApp.icns) set up for my Cocoa App. How can I access an `NSImage` representation of the icon from within my application?

Something like the following would be perfect:

```
NSImage * iconImage = [MyApplication defaultIconAsImage];
```

But I'm sure it isn't *that* easy :)

I can, of course, get a path to the icon file as follows:

```
NSString * iconPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"icns"];
```

But it seems to me that there should be some kind of standard way to access *the* icon file for the application, other than calling it by name, since the name could change.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`[NSApp applicationIconImage]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/applicationIconImage)

Comment: Are you serious? Oh dear. I'm going to go hang my head in shame. Thank you for that.

Comment: Named NSApplicationIcon in Interface Builder

Answer (score 19):

Just for completeness - This is how you get the icon for any application or file on your system.

```
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"path"];
```

Pass in the path to the application bundle for an application icon or the path to a file for the icon associated with the file.

Comment: The "and" above confuses me on your sentence about paths because I only see one parameter -- `iconForFile`, not two. Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: @Volomike Yes it's a bit confusing.  I think Abizern meant 'or', not 'and'

Comment: @Mark From your comment, it looks like Abizem made the edit to clarify. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `-[NSApplication applicationIconImage]` doesn't return the correct icon when a custom icon is pasted onto the app. Then you need to do:

```
NSString* appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSImage* appIcon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:appPath];
```

(Reference the dock icon code I wrote for Chromium: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/dock_icon.mm)

Comment: perfect! You saved my bacon.

Comment: This is also good if you want to get all of the available representations as `[NSApp applicationIconImage]` seems to only return 1.